# am i finding the force correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, acceleration

I am trying to see if I am doing a problem correctly. Problem

> Suppose you carry a 50kg sack of potatoes up two flights of stairs, a total height of 10m. How much work did you do? If it took you 20seconds, what was your power outlet?

(I am NOT looking for the answer, I am just trying to see if I am doing this correctly).

Based on what I have learned to find Work you must do this equation:
$W = Fd$ (force x displacement)

This is where I am a little confused. Not sure what the force is, but going off of my notes to find the force you must do this equation:
$F = ma$ (mass x acceleration).

I already know the mass is 50kg, but to find acceleration I must find it in m/s^2. (Where I think I am getting this wrong). So I know that our meters is 10, and our seconds is 20 (10 m high, and 20 seconds going up stairs), but to find it squared I would do 10/20 / 20 m/s^2 which equals 0.025 m/s^2 for my acceleration.

Going back to finding force I can now plug in my acceleration of 0.025 as follows:

$F = (50kg) \times (0.025m/s^2) J$

$F = 1.25 N$

$W = (1.25) \times (10)$

$W = 12.5 J$

Did I do this correctly? If not, instead of answers, let me know what I did wrong, and maybe like a hint at what I should do next. I appreciate any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused by using $F=ma$, since, as you walk up the stairs, you are not accelerating, because you walk with a constant velocity. On the sack, we find a net force $F=0$. But, there is gravity acting, such that the force that you execute is just opposite to gravity: $F=mg$. The work you put in is then $W=F\times d$, and thus $W=mgh$. Surprise, surprise, this is also exactly the change in potential energy in the system, which you might have in your notes.

Comment: I see. Now what would gravitational acceleration be since it wasn't provided? Is there a constant value for gravitational acceleration? Doing a quick google search I found that g= 9.80665 metres (32.1740 ft) per s² is for Earth, but I feel like since we are walking up stairs there must be more gravitational force since the person is also using force against gravity by walking up the stairs.

Comment: $g$ is nearly constant throughout the earth, but taking 6 significant digit does not make sense, you can always safely assume $g=9.8m/s^2$, as it varies slightly ($~0.02m/s^2$) between poles and equator

Comment: It is about the work to lift the sack, not about the work done to lift the sack AND the person. Also, the mass of the person is not provided in the question.

Comment: Omg I am so dumb. I just realized that, due to my programming experience, when you want something to free fall the acceleration must be -9.8. So if you are going against gravity, it would also need to be 9.8. Well, I feel stupid. Thank you!

Comment: @Eeeearth Don't feel stupid. You phrases your question properly and learned something now. We have all been there, don't worry!

Comment: `phrased' (editing comments is not an option)

Comment: @New_new_newbie Typo, not that important